# How do I get data from only the top few XML entries using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm pretty new to jquery and ajax. I've made an XML file that I use to dynamically make a news page. On the other pages of my site, I have a news bar that updates from the same file. Currently, the news bar loops through every news item. What I would like is if it only took the first (top) four  entries instead of every single one. I just can't find an example of the syntax relevant to what I'm trying to do.
Thanks.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
                url: 'news/news.xml',
                dataTyper: 'xml',
                success: function(xml) {

                    $(xml).find('story').each(function(){                 
                        $('.news-lineup').append(
                            '<div class="news-item">' +
                                '<p class="news-item-date">' +
                                    $(this).find('date').text() +
                                '</p>' +
                                '<a href="news.html#' +
                                    $(this).find('link').text() +
                                    '">' +
                                    '<img src="images/'+
                                        $(this).find('imagefile').text() +
                                        '" class="news-story-bar-image">' +
                                    '<p class="news-item-title">' +
                                        $(this).find('title').text() +
                                    '</p>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '<p class="news-item-blurb">' +
                                    $(this).find('blurb').text() +
                                '</p>' +
                            '</div>'
                        );                    
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: you know how to use a for don't you?

Comment: you are just manipulating the DOM elements, then you should go to use "for" loop instead to use "$.each", as for loop is faster than "$each", We use "$.each" if we need to scoping as well with loop and if need to implement chaining as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your question is not clear, I think you are looking for a loop that will append first 4 results into the news bar. You can break the loop after desired number of entities.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
            url: 'news/news.xml',
            dataTyper: 'xml',
            success: function(xml) {
                var x=0;
                $(xml).find('story').each(function(){
                    x++;                 
                    $('.news-lineup').append(
                        '<div class="news-item">' +
                            '<p class="news-item-date">' +
                                $(this).find('date').text() +
                            '</p>' +
                            '<a href="news.html#' +
                                $(this).find('link').text() +
                                '">' +
                                '<img src="images/'+
                                    $(this).find('imagefile').text() +
                                    '" class="news-story-bar-image">' +
                                '<p class="news-item-title">' +
                                    $(this).find('title').text() +
                                '</p>' +
                            '</a>' +
                            '<p class="news-item-blurb">' +
                                $(this).find('blurb').text() +
                            '</p>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );                    
                });
                if(x==4){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Oh thanks. Yeah, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If  you are using only jquery, xml and ajax, then you will get the complete xml data in the client side. To get only selective data from the xml you need to write the code in the server side(PHP, JSP, Python..) which can process your xml file according to your logic and provide you with the required data on the client side.

For reference you can refer http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

In this instead of writing all the data in the php file, you can dump your xml file in the variable, process it and send the processed data to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I also just discovered the slice command, and also that it works on arrays. The following minor change to the original seems to work just as well:

```
$(xml).find('story').slice(0, 3).each(function(){
    //code here
});
```